# Estilização formulário

Tags: html, css, formulário

Boa tarde,

Estou querendo deixar o formulário do jeito que está na imagem, sendo que quando eu utilizo form dentro de form na hora de ajeitar a parte do backend não funciona. Tentei modificar o form interno com div para poder fazer o alinhamento sendo que não fica da mesma forma.

```js
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
 position: relative;
}

.container:after, .container:before {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}

.container:after {
 clear: both;
}

.grid-1, .grid-2, .grid-3, .grid-4, .grid-5, .grid-6, .grid-7, .grid-8, .grid-9, .grid-10, .grid-11, .grid-12, .grid-13, .grid-14, .grid-15, .grid-16, .grid-1-3 {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.grid-1  {width: 40px;}
.grid-2  {width: 100px;}
.grid-3  {width: 160px;}
.grid-4  {width: 220px;}
.grid-5  {width: 280px;}
.grid-6  {width: 340px;}
.grid-7  {width: 400px;}
.grid-8  {width: 460px;}
.grid-9  {width: 520px;}
.grid-10  {width: 580px;}
.grid-11  {width: 640px;}
.grid-12  {width: 700px;}
.grid-13  {width: 760px;}
.grid-14  {width: 820px;}
.grid-15  {width: 880px;}
.grid-16  {width: 940px;}
.grid-1-3 {width: 300px;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 788px) and (max-width: 979px) {
 .container {
 width: 768px;
}
 
.grid-1  {width: 28px;}
.grid-2  {width: 76px;}
.grid-3  {width: 124px;}
.grid-4  {width: 172px;}
.grid-5  {width: 220px;}
.grid-6  {width: 268px;}
.grid-7  {width: 316px;}
.grid-8  {width: 364px;}
.grid-9  {width: 412px;}
.grid-10  {width: 460px;}
.grid-11  {width: 508px;}
.grid-12  {width: 556px;}
.grid-13  {width: 604px;}
.grid-14  {width: 652px;}
.grid-15  {width: 700px;}
.grid-16  {width: 748px;}
.grid-1-3 {width: 236px;}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 787px) {
 .container {
 width: 300px;
}

.grid-1, .grid-2, .grid-3, .grid-4, .grid-5, .grid-6, .grid-7, .grid-8, .grid-9, .grid-10, .grid-11, .grid-12, .grid-13, .grid-14, .grid-15, .grid-16, .grid-1-3 {
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 float: none;
}

}
```

```css
.tipo-de-servico select {
 display: block;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
 background: #f2f2f3;
 outline: none;
}

.contato_form {
 padding-right: 20px;
}

.contato_form label {
 display: block;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.contato_form input{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 border: 4px solid #c0c0c0;
 background: none;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif 
}

.form_right {
 margin-top: 14px;
}

.form_right label {
 display: block;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.form_right input{
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 border: 4px solid #c0c0c0;
 background: none;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif 
}

.form_textarea textarea {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
 border: 4px solid #c0c0c0;
 background: none;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif 
}

.form_textarea label {
 display: block;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#orcamento .btn {
 text-align: center; 
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="orcamento">
    <div class="container">
     <h1 class="titulo">Orçamento</h1>
     
     <form action="" class="contato_form grid-8">
      <label for="nome">Nome *</label>
      <input type="text" id="nome">
      
      <label for="email">E-mail *</label>
      <input type="text" id="email">
 
      <label for="tel">Telefone</label>
      <input type="text" id="tel">
 
      <label for="tel">Celular *</label>
      <input type="text" id="cel">
 
      <label for="tel">Endereço com número do prédio</label>
      <input type="text" id="endereco">     
     </form>
     
     <form action="" class="contato_form grid-8">
      <div class="tipo-de-servico">
       <label for="">Tipo de serviço *</label>
       <select name="" id="">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="">Autovistoria Predial</option>
        <option value="">Laudo Técnico</option>
        <option value="">Laudo Técnico de Recebimento de Obra</option>
        <option value="">Laudo Técnico de Reforma</option>
        <option value="">Laudo Técnico de Vizinhança</option>
        <option value="">Laudo Técnico de Edifício em Garantia</option>
        <option value="">Vistoria Locativa</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </form>
 
     <form action="" class="form_right grid-8">
       <label for="">Nº de andares</label>
       <input type="text" id="numeroAndares">
 
       <label for="">Nº de aptos ou salas</label>
       <input type="text" id="numeroAptoOuSalas">
 
       <label for="">Nº de elevadores</label>
       <input type="text" id="numeroElevadores">
 
       <label for="">Idade do prédio</label>
       <input type="text" id="idadePredio">
     </form>
     <form class="form_textarea grid-16">
      <label for="detalhe">Detalhe sua solicitação</label>
      <textarea id="detalhe"></textarea>
     </form>
     <button type="submit" class="btn grid-4">Enviar</button> 
    </div> 
   </section>
```

[image: Orçamento]

Comment: Cara não entendi entendi direto, qui ficou exatamente como na sua imagem http://prntscr.com/p2dbew, e no código são 3 forms, vc quer fazer o submit dos 3 clicando em um btn só? No geral não entendi bem o que vc precisa nem de layout nem de função...

Comment: É, isso mesmo "fazer o submit dos 3 clicando em um btn só".